# Trying to verify user with token but emailAddressVerificationToken undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to verify the user by clicking the email link through sendgrid. You can see below the code that I'm trying to pass values.emailAddressVerificationToken so it gets passed to my actions file, however I'm getting emailAddressVerificationToken undefined inside my verify component.

[image]

verify component

```
  import { verifyEmailSubmit } from "../../stores/Auth/actions";
    // gets the token in the URL
    getVerifiedEmailToken = () => {
    const query = parse(this.props.location.search);
    return query.token;
  };

     componentDidMount(values) {
        // this means the user has clicked the link, so we'll verify the email here
        const { verifyEmail } = this.props;
        console.log(verifyEmail);
        console.log(values);
        values.emailAddressVerificationToken = this.getVerifiedEmailToken();
        verifyEmail(values);
      }

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
      verifyEmail: params => dispatch(verifyEmailSubmit(params))
    });

    export default withRouter(
      connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
      )(VerifyEmailComplete)
    );
```

auth action file

```
    export function verifyEmailSubmit(params) {
      const mutation = `
      mutation {
        verifyEmail(
          emailAddressVerificationToken: "${params.emailAddressVerificationToken}"
        )
      }      
    `;

      return dispatch => {
        dispatch(authInProgress());

        return ApolloService.mutate({ mutation })
          .then(response => {
            const { verifyEmail } = response.data;

            dispatch(resetAppMessages());
            dispatch(verifyEmailSuccess());
            return verifyEmail;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            dispatch(verifyEmailFailure());
            // Need to throw this error so that the callee (react component) can use this error in it's own catch block
            throw error;
          });
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to this line in componentDidMount

```
values.emailAddressVerificationToken = this.getVerifiedEmailToken();
// values is undefined. react don't send any argument
```

`componentDidMount` do not send any argument and you are accepting argument, due to which value of `values` is undefined. Please refer [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Comment: Hi, I did this instead but still getting undefined.


```
  checkVerifyEmail = values => {
    const { verifyEmail } = this.props;
    values.emailAddressVerificationToken = this.getVerifiedEmailToken();
    verifyEmail(values);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("passed componentDidMount");
    this.checkVerifyEmail();
  }

Comment: Thats what I said the argument in `componentDidMount` would always be undefined. What you expect values to be